# patent has more drawings than images shown on google

Tags: specification

Why does the google patent site show fewer drawings than listed in the patent

see this has 9 images of drawings:
http://www.google.com/patents/USD678656

while the actual patent has much more - 21:
http://patft1.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=D678656.PN.&OS=PN/D678656&RS=PN/D678656

Comment: Just looked at it from my ipad,all 21 are there if you do the horizontal scrolling.

Comment: I think there are only 10 images - not 21 - even if you scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake - each 'page' can have multiple drawings.  The images on both links show multiple drawings on a single page.